# php ziparchive renamed file is empty

Tags: php, file, rename, php-ziparchive

I'm using php to create a ziparchive which contains some images. This works fine exept when i try to rename the files. This is the code that works:

```
$zip_archive->open(tempnam("tmp", "zip"), ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $path = $image['path'];
  $title = $image['title'];
  if(file_exists($path)){
    $zip_file->addFile($path, pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
  }
}
$zip_archive->close();
```

$images is an array and could look like this:

```
$images = array(
    'path' => array(
        'folder/title1.jpg',
        'folder/title2.jpg'
    ),
    'title' => array(
        'new_name1.jpg',
        'new_name2.jpg'
    )
)
```

I would like to name the image as its title.

```
$zip_file->addFile($path, $title);
```

But whats happening is that the files in the zip with the title as name are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $image is a array or path?what you stored in $image?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question. what is $imge and $title.

Comment: $images is an array. Each entry is also an array with two entries: path and title which are both Strings. Path is the absolute path to the file/image i want to store in the ziparchive. Title contains the new name for the file/image in the ziparchive.

Comment: can you please update your question with an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run this

```
$images = array(
    'path' => array(
        'folder/title1.jpg',
        'folder/title2.jpg'
    ),
    'title' => array(
        'new_name1.jpg',
        'new_name2.jpg'
    )
);

$i = 0;
foreach($images as $image)
    var_dump($image, $i++);
```

I get

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "folder/title1.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "folder/title2.jpg"
}
int(0)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "new_name1.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "new_name2.jpg"
}
int(1)
```

This means that these

```
$path = $image['path'];
$title = $image['title'];
```

are both `NULL`

You have two ways to fix this:

- Change the array to look like

  ```
  $images = array(
      [0] => array(
          'path' => 'folder/title1.jpg',
          'title' => 'new_name1.jpg'
      ),
      [1] => array(
          'path' => 'folder/title2.jpg'
          'title' => 'new_name2.jpg',
      )
  );
  ```

  in this case your initial code should work
- Change the way to access the array, doing something like

  ```
  for($i = 0;$i < count($images['path']);$i++)
  {
      $path = $image['path'][$i];
      $title = $image['title'][$i];
  }
  ```

  This way you are sure that path and title of the image will have the same index, but it's not recommanded to do so because the array must be ordered.

I suggest you to change the array, your code should be ok that way